# What does payment status "EXPIRED" in PayPal Adaptive Payments mean?

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have several PayPal Adaptive payments with an "EXPIRED" status (in an application that accepts payments on behalf of a seller). They are explicitly approved payments, meaning money changes hands as soon as the sender accepts the payment.

[The documentation for the PaymentDetails API call](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_APPaymentDetails) doesn't mention EXPIRED in the list of possible statuses.

Could you direct me to some other documentation or explain what this status means?

Answer (score 2):

Some more googling brought up [this forum thread](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/forums/adaptive-payments-api/paymentdetails-api-operation):

> A status of expired means that a PayKey has expired and cannot be used. A PayKey has a life of three hours, after which it cannot be used to complete the payment.
>   If this occurs you will need to generate a new PayKey with a new trackingID using the Pay API call as you did previously. The reason the tracking ID is not released back and allowed to be used again is because it would cause issues with dublicate tracking ID's in yours and our system.

So, an EXPIRED Adaptive Payment is one that has been created but never paid, so you can safely create a duplicate new one instead.

Comment: Not only did PayPal delegate support to stackoverflow, but now product documentation as well?  The future for developers certainly looks bleak.  Anyhow, thanks for this informative answer.

Comment: Always check for transaction status codes, before trusted the pay info status.